# Laravel BelongsTo relation - where on instance attribute

Tags: laravel

I have the following model:

```php
class Order extends Model
{
  public function user(): BelongsTo
  {
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'shipping_email_address', 'email_address')
                ->where('customer_id', $this->customer_id);
  }
}
```

Now when I call `Order::with('user')->get()`, it doesn't load the users.

I can access the user just fine when using `Order::first()->user`.

Is it possible to eager load a relationship with a where clause on a model instance attribute (like `$this->customer_id`)? Or is there another way to make a relationship based on two columns?

Comment: Because in ur relation is referenced for 1 instance (you are using `$this` ). But when you try to do the same with = `Order::with('user')->get()` . Eloquent cant get `$this` because you are trying to call non-static method statically

Comment: @josanangel yeah, that's right. But is there an alternative way to get it to work?

Comment: customer_id is not a column in orders ? and a foriengKey in orders ?

Comment: @OMR `customer_id` exists as column in both `orders` and `users`

Answer (score 2):

You can do this :

Your relation :

```
 public function user()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
  }
```

Then you can make query like this :

```
$userId = 5;
$result = Order::whereHas('user',function($q) use ($userId){
  return $q->where('id',$userId);
});
```

---

Reply to your comment:

Having this relation :

```
 public function user()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
  }
```

Use this :

```
Order::with('user')->get()
```

This will retrieve all orders with its users. If you have some problem on that query then you have a wrong relationship. Make sure you have a foregin key in Orders table, if  you dont espcify some foreign key on eloquent relationship, eloquent will understand than foreign key is : user_id, if not, especify putting more arguments to this function :

```
$this->belongsTo(User::class,...,...);
```

With function make join according to relationship configuration, just make sure the relation is ok. And all work fine !

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want the orders of only a single user. I'd like to retrieve all the orders, with their associated user.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep your current flow, i would do it like so. Thou the `josanangel` solution is most optimal.

When getting orders include them using with. All these are now eager loaded.

```
$orders = Order::with('user');
```

Now utilize eloquent getters to filter the user by `customer_id`. This is not done in queries, as that would produce one query per attribute access.

```
public function getUserByCustomerAttribute() {
    if ($this->user->customer_id === $this->customer_id) {
        return $this->user;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Simply accessing the eloquent getter, would trigger your custom logic and make what you are trying to do possible.

```
$orders = Order::with('user')->get();

foreach ($orders as $order) {
    $order->user_by_customer; // return user if customer id is same
}
```

Comment: Your query need a `->get()` to be executed, then u can foreach it as collection

Comment: Offcourse was just written too quick in a break at work :)

Answer (score -1):

Your wrong decleration of the relationship here is what is making this not function correctly.
From the laravel's documentation:

> Eloquent determines the default foreign key name by examining the name of the relationship method and suffixing the method name with a _ followed by the name of the parent model's primary key column. So, in this example, Eloquent will assume the Post model's foreign key on the comments table is post_id.

in your case the problem is that laravel is searching for the User using `user_id` column so the correct way to declare the relation is

```
public function user()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'customer_id'); // tell laravel to search the user using this column in the Order's table.
  }
```

Everthing should work as intended after that.
Source: [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many)

Comment: Thanks, but that's not the issue. I want to query both on `user_id` and `customer_id`

Comment: @Jan-PaulKleemans Ah ok I thought the problem was the customer_id but now I understand. I don't think laravel supports relationships with 2 columns in it's core.

Comment: yeah, there's https://github.com/topclaudy/compoships to do that but i'd like to use a 'native' solution. Thanks for your help.